# Can we unload [load]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[load](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/load) is undefined, has zero followers, and currently has 59 questions.  These include the following uses of the term:

- command in various software
- parameter or setting in various commands
- data file input action
- install software
- initiate software instance
- boot process
- computer resource usage or demand of various and sundry kinds
- electrical resistance or power consumption
- network traffic
- testing under specific resource utilization
- specific parameter in various reports
- unnecessary decoration

Possibly others; I stopped looking.  With this many meanings (and no followers), the tag isn't really serving a proper tag function as-is.  However, it sort of imparts a useful context, and some specific load-related meaning is central to the question in most cases.  So I suspect it would be better to replace it with more specific tags than to just delete it.  That may mean some new tags, or other existing tags.

I've done a little cleanup and may do a few more, but most of these questions would be better handled by people with more familiarity with the subject matter.  We can whittle this down if people will take a quick look at the questions and improve the tags for questions they're familiar with (or delete the tag if you know it isn't important to that question).

---

**Update:**  The deed is done.  Everyone, thanks.

Comment: The question should have been written as `un[load]` :)

Answer (score 4):

From a quick glance over the remaining 20 questions with that tag, it looks like all or nearly all of them are using "load" to mean "CPU load."

I propose that they be re-tagged to "cpu-usage" or "high-cpu-usage".

Then possibly the tag "load" should be blacklisted.  Or make it auto-suggest "cpu-usage" when someone types in load.

Comment: Thanks.  cpu-usage might get misused because it could cover a lot of different kinds of things.  high-cpu-usage might be too restrictive, because some questions are about comparing different levels.  But what about cpu-load, as in your first sentence?  That seems to cover it and properly limits the definition.  It also contains "load", which would automatically suggest the tag, as you mentioned?

Comment: @fixer1234, that was my first thought but I checked and there is no "cpu-load" tag right now.  Possibly "cpu-load" should be aliased to "cpu-usage" but I don't want to get too radical with my suggestions; I'm not as active on Superuser as Unix&Linux.

Comment: What the heck, let's get radical and live life on the edge.  I can create a new tag.  :-)  I'll give it a little time for feedback to see if anyone thinks it's a bad tag or has a better suggestion, but I think your initial thought was a winner.